Minimizing a function of a 2d array
I have a free energy density function that I have to minimize. The function looks as follows,

f = 1/2*(k1 sin^2 theta + k2 cos^2 theta)*(del theta/del x)^2  +  1/2*k3*(del the*ta/del z)^2  -  1/2*sin^2 (p*x)*cos^2 theta

I need to find the distribution theta(x,z) for which the integration over the free energy (total energy) will be minimum.
The boundary conditions are, theta(x,z=0) = 0; and theta(x,z=d) =0.
Previously, I solved for the one dimensional case.
f_1d = (del theta/del x)^2 + b*cos^2 theta
There, I used scipy.optimize.minimize to minimize this and find theta(x). The code for the 1d case is given below,
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.optimize import minimize 

def U(th):
    n = len(th)
    b = 1.5
    term_1 = sum( (th[i+1]-th[i])**2 for i in range(n-1) )
    term_2 = b * sum( np.cos(th[i])**2 for i in range(n) )
    return term_1 + term_2 

def con_fun(th):
    return np.array([th[0], th[-1]]) 

initial = np.random.rand(10)

constraints = ({'type':'eq', 'fun':con_fun})

result = minimize(U, initial, constraints = constraints, method = 'SLSQP' )
opt_A = result.x
plt.plot(opt_A, marker='o')

plt.grid()

This code works fine.
But how do I solve for the 2d case (theta(x,z))? I tried using numpy.concatenate but this makes the program too slow for array sizes of (50,100).
It will be very helpful if someone can help me with some methods to solve the 2d case.

How did you try concatenate? It's hard to fix your code when you only show the one that's not broken...

In your 1D case, why doesn't your derivative include a dx term? Where do you compute the integral?

minimize wants a 1d initial, which it will pass a 1d th.  But you can reshape it to 2d to calculate U value (which still has to be scalar)

@MadPhysicist, I am just looking for insights on how the 2d case could be solved, I am not sure if using concatenate was relevant, so did not add the code.

@jared, Just for checking if the code works, I assumed dx = 1. And I performed summation instead of integration, to obtain the total energy.

@hpaulj, Yes, that is a method. But for large 2d arrays, the 1d equivalent will be very large and can take too much time to run. Although this will work, but I wondered if there are better methods.

I am not sure to fully understand the problem, but here are some tips : you can speed up the U function with Numba (with basic loops), but I expect the search space the be significantly bigger. It is worth a try to profile this and see what is actually slow.
